# Comparing Spark 2 DataFrame's

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Spark/Scala.
I have a master data frame which consists of over 100 million records

```
+--------+
|  ttm_id|
+--------+
|39622109|
|39622178|
|39578322|
+--------+
```

And a changelist DataFrame which has around 40 million records

```
+----------+--------+
|__change__|  ttm_id|
+----------+--------+
|    DELETE|18001570|
|    DELETE|   50520|
|    DELETE|  144440|
|    DELETE|   93130|
|    DELETE|   93140|
+----------+--------+
```

How would I go about comparing these two data frames so that:

If ***__change__*** = DELETE and masterlist.ttm_id = changeset.ttm_id then remove matching ttm_id record from the Masterlist

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like @MaxU's solution using `except`.  Here's another approach using `left_anti` join:

```
master.join( changelist.where($"__change__" === "DELETE"),
  Seq("ttm_id"), "left_anti"
)
```

Note that for large DataFrames, this approach can be expensive.

Comment: I liked this answer the best. Now I have a new dataframe which has the records that need to be added from the ChangeSet to the MasterSet, where ChangeSet.auditid != MasterSet.auditid. How would I best create a new dataframe with joining the DF created from your code to the InsertDF?

Comment: @Phil Baines, sorry I don't think I understand your new question.  Given that the requirement seems rather different from the original question's, I suggest that you post it as a separate question with sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you can do it using the following query:

```
select * from masterlist
where not exists (select 1 from changeset
                  where masterlist.ttm_id = changeset.ttm_id
                    and masterlist.__change__='DELETE');
```

Demo:

```
scala> m.show
+--------+
|  ttm_id|
+--------+
|39622109|
|39622178|
|39578322|
+--------+


scala> c.show
+----------+--------+
|__change__|  ttm_id|
+----------+--------+
|    DELETE|39622109|
|    DELETE|   50520|
+----------+--------+


scala> val q="""
     | select * from masterlist
     | where not exists (select ttm_id from changeset
     |                   where masterlist.ttm_id = changeset.ttm_id
     |                     and changeset.__change__='DELETE')
     | """
q: String =
"
select * from masterlist
where not exists (select ttm_id from changeset
                  where masterlist.ttm_id = changeset.ttm_id
                    and changeset.__change__='DELETE')
"

scala> val res = spark.sql(q)
res: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [ttm_id: int]

scala> res.show
+--------+
|  ttm_id|
+--------+
|39622178|
|39578322|
+--------+
```

Another solution:

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

scala> m.withColumn("__change__", lit("DELETE")).except(c.select("ttm_id","__change__")).select("ttm_id").show
+--------+
|  ttm_id|
+--------+
|39578322|
|39622178|
+--------+
```

Comment: Yes, that is the correct format for SQL however looking to replicate that using Scala :)

Comment: Except will not work as the two tables have different column counts (change set has extra column to indicate whether to insert or delete for Master) But I am happy for the exposure to a different way to do it in the future

Answer (score 0):

Broadcasting a smaller *dataframe* should help reduce the *shuffle* needed for joining the *dataframes*.

You can use `join`, `filter` and `drop` after broadcasting the `changedset` *dataframe* to get your desired result

```
val broadcastedMasterList = sc.broadcast(changeset)
masterlist.join(broadcastedMasterList.value, Seq("ttm_id"), "left")
  .filter($"__change__".isNull || $"__change__" =!= "DELETE")
  .drop("__change__")
  .show(false)
```

I hope the answer is helpful.

Comment: Doesn't Spark perform a BroadcashHashJoin by itself if the table is small enough?

Comment: @philantrovert, default is shuffleHashJoin for spark :)